# javascript prototype definition error

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this function(class) which I define a prototype function.

```
function testit(t,l, w, h, c, p) {
    this.div;
    this.obj = { "top": t, "left": l, "width": w, "height": h, "color": c };
}

testit.prototype.showit = function () {
     this.div = $("<div />")
        .css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "top": this.obj.top,
            "left": this.obj.left,
            "width": this.obj.width,
            "height": this.obj.height,
            "border": "1px solid " + this.obj.color
        })
        .appendTo(p);
}
```

When running the following code -

```
var aa;

aa = new testit(100, 100, 100, 100, "#CCCCCC", "body");
aa.showit();
```

I get the following error -

[Unhandled exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4YWH.png)

What is wrong with the prototype definition ?

Comment: Where are you instantiating `testit` in relation to the class definition?

Comment: After defining `p`, there was no problem with your code for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't cause the error you've listed (see the snippet I added to your question), unless of course you have a global `p` variable that's not a string or DOM element, which case I suppose it could.

It does have a **different** error: `p` is not defined at the point you use it. You need to remember `p` in the constructor (`this.p = p;` perhaps) and then use that property (`this.p`) when calling `appendTo`:

```js
function testit(t,l, w, h, c, p) {
    this.div;
    this.obj = { "top": t, "left": l, "width": w, "height": h, "color": c };
    this.p = p;
}

testit.prototype.showit = function () {
     this.div = $("<div />")
    .css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": this.obj.top,
        "left": this.obj.left,
        "width": this.obj.width,
        "height": this.obj.height,
        "border": "1px solid " + this.obj.color
    })
    .appendTo(this.p);
}

var aa;

aa = new testit(100, 100, 100, 100, "#CCCCCC", "body");
aa.showit();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You'll also have to beware of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) if you're calling `showit` in (say) an event callback.